# Custom 404 Not Working for /index

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Our WordPress custom 404 works great, however when you attempt to access http://example.com/index the custom 404 is not displayed.  Instead, the default GoDaddy 404 page is displayed for only this URL.

Just to be clear, the issue is with "/index" and not "/index.php"

I tried a few ways around this but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Using the genesis theme, latest WordPress version, all plugins up to date and generally no problems with the site.

Is there a specific HTACCESS entry I can add to handle this url?

This is the contents of my root htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Fixed posted by  anubhava, added the following line to my htaccess file above the WordPress entry:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Try placing `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: That did it, thanks anubhava!  I'm curious about the why this was needed, and/or how the provided code works.

Comment: I have added this as answer with some explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by placing this line:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

at top of your .htaccess.

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.html` or `/file.php` whatever is found your directory.

Reason why you are getting 404 for `/index` URI is probably you have some `index.*` file lying in your directory when `MultiViews` is turned on.